# Pyspark Mongodb connector append to array

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using `mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.1.1` and I'm trying to save a dataframe to MongoDB.
Here are my Mongodb write configuration and code:

```py
    def write_mongo_batches(self,df): 
        return      df.writeStream.option('checkpointLocation',self.checkpointLocation).foreachBatch(self.write_mongo_collection).start()
    

    def write_mongo_collection(self,df,epoch_id):
        df\
            .write\
            .format('mongodb') \
            .mode('append') \
            .option('database',self.database)\
            .option('collection', self.collection_name)\
            .option('idFieldList',self.shardkey)\
            .option('operationType','update')\
            .save()
```

My input is a postgres table with 2 columns `collection_id` and `subscriber_jid`.

My spark transformation code looks like this:

```py
def create_subscriptions_table(df):
    split_array = F.split(F.col('collection_id'),'\\.')
    return df\
        .filter(df.collection_id.isNotNull() & df.subscriber_jid.isNotNull())\
        .withColumn('namespaceId',F.when(F.size(split_array) > 1,split_array.getItem(0)).otherwise("DEFAULT"))\
        .withColumn('collectionId',F.col('collection_id'))\
        .withColumn('subscriberIds',F.array(F.col('subscriber_jid')))\
        .withColumn('_id',F.col('collection_id'))\
        .select(F.col('_id'),F.col('namespaceId'),F.col('collectionId'),F.col('subscriberIds'))
```

My output MongoDB document looks like this where `subscriberIds` is an array:

```
{
  "_id": "collectionId",
  "collectionId": "collectionId",
  "namespaceId": "DEFAULT",
  "subscriberIds": [
    "subscriberId1"
  ]
}
```

I am trying to append the `subscriber_jid` from the input and append it to `subscriberIds` array in the output.

My problem is that I am not able to append the `subscriberIds` to the array. It is replacing the document as a whole and `subscriberIds` array always has 1 entry.

What am I doing wrong? How can I append another `subscriber_jid` to `subscriberIds` array?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253090/spark-mongodb-connector-array-push-operation) on SO but it's unanswered.

Comment: You may need to do group by operation on the dataframe and populate the array and write it to mongodb